# HTML5 canvas game spawn interval

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a game using HTML5 Canvas and Javascript. What i am trying to do is make a ladybug move around the screen at a specific interval. When the mouse hovers over the lady bug it will increase the interval and spawn in a different place. Right now i have it so the ladybug spawns in different places when you refresh the page. I dont know how to make it update on its own or how to get it to detect mouse hover.

thank you in advance.

This is what i have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="480"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var posX = (Math.random() * 520) + 1;
  var posY = (Math.random() * 400) + 1;
  var ladybug = new Image();
  var background = new Image();
  var velocity = 5;
  var FPS = 30;

  update();
  draw();
  background();
  function background() {
      background.onload = function () {
          context.drawImage(background, 50, 50);
      }
      background.src = 'Images/grass.png';
  }
  function draw() {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
      context.fillStyle = "black"; // Set color to black
      context.font = "bold 16px Arial";
      context.fillText("Sup Bro!", posX, posY);
      ladybug.onload = function () {
          context.drawImage(ladybug, posX, posY);
      };

      ladybug.src = 'Images/Ladybug.png';

  }
  function update() {


  }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

**First. Updating it on its own.**

To make bug move around the screen, you should use periodically update:

```
// instead of update() use setInterval(update, 1000 / FPS)
//update();
setInterval(update, 1000 / FPS);
```

Where 1000 = 1 second and `1000 / FPS` = exactly FPS runs per second. You can check in your browser console, that it executes 30 times per second by adding logging to update:

```
function update(){
  console.log("Here we go");
}
```

But be careful: this will spam your browser console hard.

Here you should erase old bug from canvas, recalculate coordinates and draw new in new place.

Next thing is go and fix your background. Rename your `background` function to `drawBackground` (or whatever), 'cause you have an error: background already defined and it is an Image.

**Second. Detecting hover.**

To check if user is hovering over bug you should use onmousemove event on canvas:

```
function init() {
  canvas.onmousemove = function(event) {
    if (window.event) event = window.event; // IE hack
    var mousex = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var mousey = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
    mousemove(mousex, mousey);
  }
}
function mousemove(x, y) {
  console.log (x, y);
  // here check, if mousex and mousey is in rectangle (x, y, x + width, y + width)
  // where x, y, width and height are parameters of lady bug
}
```

**PS:**

There are a lot of nasty frameworks out there for canvas and manipulating html and dom. They make life easier. But it is good to do it in purely JS a few time before go exploring them.

Comment: Thank you for this, it helped me.

If i wanted to make it so i just clicked on the image and it displayed an alert, how would i do that?

Comment: @justinC19 You could use `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` events. Just in the same way as with `onmousemove`.